# How to secure a simple PHP script that sends emails?

Tags: php, security

In a simple contact form, the HTML form triggers a Php script :

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">.....</form>
```

This email.php sends me an email :

```
<?php
    $mess=$_POST['name']. "\r\n" .$_POST['site']. "\r\n" .$_POST['email']. "\r\n" .$_POST['meta']. "\r\n" .$_POST['message'];
    mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Subject', $mess);
?>
```

The HTML is using jQuery validate plugin, but nothing like this on the Php side.

A Security expert told me **how insanely unsecure this php script was**.

What can I do to enhance security ?

Comment: "Security" is a large subject, but as a start, **do not trust user input**, do not even assume they all presents. A simple POST request with no parameter will cause your script to complain (e.g. `$_POST` do not have index "name").

Comment: What exactly did they say was so "insanely insecure" about it?

Comment: surely if they where a proper security expert they would also be able to advise you on how to fix said insane unsecure script parts.

Comment: @AlexHowansky : The expert said this : _You do not have a form token to prevent cross site request forgery – that's the reason you receive email when someone hits that page. You do not check if the required fields are filled in. You also do not perform any kind of filtering whatsoever which means that I can very easily use a series of nasty attacks to figure out which mail reader and OS you use and then send a series of 0-day attacks I can buy for pennies on the dark web to hack you._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your "security expert" saw you using raw `$_POST` data and using the `mail()` function, and he freaked out, but didn't stop to actually check how bad things were.

He has a point in that using `$_POST` without doing any validation on it is almost always a recipe for being hacked, but in fact in this particular case I don't think it's too bad, because you are the only recipient (so it's not going to be used for spam, which is the main thing to worry about in these cases), and because the body is plain text (so a hacker can't send you any nasty scripts or attachments).

Without any validation, you could get some really weird emails as a result of hackers trying to find a way around your defences, but not too much else.

PHP's `mail()` function is a well-known soft target for hackers because there is an awful lot of insecure code out there that uses it. However the real danger with `mail()` tends to be if you use the `headers` parameter (ie to set things like the sender address, etc), which you haven't used. Since you're not using `headers`, the risks are a lot lower, and mainly limited to making it easy for someone to mailbomb you.

If you are still worried about the security of the `mail()` function, the best solution is to use a library like phpMailer instead.

To be honest, my advice whenever anyone wants to use PHP's `mail()` function is always to use phpMailer or Swiftmailer instead. And it's not even just about security; even for simple cases, they can make your code a lot easier to read and maintain.

Comment: That's very clear. I'll study phpMailer alternative function.

Regarding what the security expert said : 
_You do not have a form token to prevent cross site request forgery – that's the reason you receive email when someone hits that page. You do not check if the required fields are filled in. You also do not perform any kind of filtering whatsoever which means that I can very easily use a series of nasty attacks to figure out which mail reader and OS you use and then send a series of 0-day attacks I can buy for pennies on the dark web to hack you._

Comment: I checked that the fields are not empty, but in the HTML part, using jQuery validate. 
Based on your exaplanation, risks are limited to me receiving loads of emails. I guess this is reffered to by _0-days attacks_ ?

Comment: Re expert's comments: (1) CSRF: Sure, someone could call your email.php URL from anywhere; it's not ideal but there's no inherent security risk with it here, the worst risk is getting mailbombed; (2) Checking required fields: Yes, you do need to do this; PHP will issue warnings if you access them without them being passed. But other than the warning messages, it's not a problem in this case. (3) Filtering: Since the email is going to arrive as plain text and isn't modifying the headers, that mitigates the attack risk here. You should still validate to be sure, but generally I think you're ok.

Comment: Re validation: You say you're doing jQuery validation. This is an important point: You should always do your validation on the server. You can do it in the browser *as well* if you like to make things easier for the user, but to be secure validation must be done on the server because a hacker can bypass any JavaScript/jQuery code very easily. In this case, you're protected somewhat by sending the mail as plain text, but you could still get mail from hackers trying to find a way around your system. Filtering/validation on the server would help with that.

Comment: The bottom line here is that your expert is broadly right in that you're not taking any of the standard security measures to protect your system. However you've kinda got lucky in that your system isn't particularly exploitable anyway. But it wouldn't have taken much more code to make it wide open to attack; eg just adding the sender's address as a 'From' header without making it secure would have turned your code into an instant spam engine.

Comment: If you want to get a deeper discussion on security of this code, you might also want to cross-post to SO's sister site http://security.stackexchange.com/. There are some real experts there who will be able to explain much more detail than I can.

Comment: That's so clear, even for a newbie. THX. I'll do research to add Php validation.

Answer (score 0):

One big flaw is that an attacker could trivially fill your inbox with malicious or junk messages which, besides being very annoying, would likely cause Google to put your domain on their spam list.

They could do this by writing a short script to call that PHP function with some arbitrary data, and loop through it for however long they want.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way of solving what you asking for. And I hope this can be useful for other askers, as I see similar questions coming op consecutively.

If you intend to make professional application and focus on your core business, then I suggest you use some secured email portals with API from like mailgun, mandrill or others. Both service offer a dash board where you can see e-mail status of how many emails are sent and delivery status, and a lot of other statistics. It is FREE for small usage. It is worth it using it, because you will solve some of following issues:

- You do not need to think about maintaining security of your smtp server
- Or even correct configuring your smtp
- Solving block and black IP addresses
- Server attack
- Spam problem
- And name the more

Both solutions provide API for PHP or other platforms.

Note: I have been my self used my own smtp server few years back, and you know all the time I put to fixing and maintaining the smtp server is not worth it, because I could spent that time doing better stuff and leave e-mail service part for professionals.